Cosmos-kit Osmosis custom RPC endpoints - Cosmos ecosystem
I got an assignment in the cosmos ecosystem. It's my first time building on Cosmos network, specifically Osmosis and I am having a problem connecting to my custom RCP endpoints, it always falls back to default - "https://rpc.cosmos.directory/osmosis"
this is the config I need to set up, but I don't think I have it correctly set up in my code.
/* OSMOSIS NODE ENDPOINTS */
RPC=https://rpc-osmosis.blockapsis.com
REST=https://lcd-osmosis.blockapsis.com
/* OSMOSIS MAINNET CONFIG */
{
id: 'osmosis-1',
name: 'Osmosis Mainnet',
defaultCurrency: {
coinDenom: 'OSMO',
coinMinimalDenom: 'uosmo',
coinDecimals: 6,
coinGeckoId: 'osmosis',
gasPriceStep: {
low: 0.0025,
average: 0.025,
high: 0.04,
},
},
gasPrice: '0.0035uosmo',
}
this is my Providers component:
 <ChainProvider
            chains={[...chains]}
            assetLists={[...assets]}
            wallets={wallets}
            endpointOptions={{
                endpoints: {
                    osmosis: {
                        rpc: ['https://rpc-osmosis.blockapsis.com'],
                        rest: ['https://lcd-osmosis.blockapsis.com']
                    }
                }
            }}

        >
            {children}
        </ChainProvider>

and this is my connect wallet logic:

    const { status, address, connect, disconnect } = useChain('osmosis');

    const cutAddress = (address: string | undefined) => {
        if (!address) return "";
        const start = address.slice(0, 2);
        const end = address.slice(-5);
        return `${start}...${end}`;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (status === 'Connected') {
            console.log('Wallet connected:', address);
        }

    }, [status, address]);

I need the custom RPC to continue in my assignment and create a Mint button and mint on chain credit account. I am new to this, so will appreciate any help in how and where to set up the config to connect to the desired chain and RPC endpoint.
Thank you very much!
PS:
I have tried following the docs in Cosmology but I think I am setting up something wrong here.
Their Chain interface does not match the config required for me to implement.

Try disabling RPC validation using isLazy:
https://docs.cosmology.zone/cosmos-kit/provider/chain-provider#islazy
